# getimagesize не возвращает данные, если в url больше 1 пробела

Tags: php

Идёт обработка картинок. Получаю данные со стороннего сервера, причём не с одного. Есть картинки, в именах которых есть пробелы. Вроде бы `urlencode()` должна решать вопросы, но она заменяет не только пробелы, но и все символы кроме букв, цифр и _. Т.к. сервера разные, то не стал заморачиваться и прикрутил так:

```
$this->image = str_replace(" ", "%20", $this->image);
```

Заменил все пробелы на %20.

Любопытная ситуация с `getimagesize()` проявилась там, где в урле встречается 2 пробела.

Пример с 1 пробелом РАБОТАЕТ:

```
$filename = 'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/1952_CDND_garbage_bags_240L_10pcs_3893%20NEW.jpg';
var_dump(getimagesize($filename));die();
```

вывод:

```
array(7) { [0]=> int(2714) [1]=> int(1303) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> string(26) "width="2714" height="1303"" ["bits"]=> int(8) ["channels"]=> int(3) ["mime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" }
```

Пример с 2 пробелами НЕ РАБОТАЕТ:

```
$filename = 'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/1020%20СD_garbage%20bags_60L_40pcs.jpg';
var_dump(getimagesize($filename));die();
```

вывод:

```
bool(false)
```

В одном из ответов на этом сайте нашёл способ

```
$a = urlencode($filename);
$a = rawurldecode($filename);
getimagesize($a)
```

он тоже не работает. Шаманил со всеми кодирующими и декодирующими функциями, но суть тут не в том. Т.к. замена пробела на %20 является корректной заменой и должно работать. Обе картинки доступны в вебе. Есть какие-то соображения по этому поводу?

Изначальная ссылка с двумя пробелами

```
http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/1020 СD_garbage bags_60L_40pcs.jpg
```

Comment: Покажите ссылки до `str_replace`. Что-то мне подсказывает, что там ссылка должна быть не `http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/1020%20СD_garbage%20bags_60L_40pcs.jpg` a `http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/1020%20%D0%A1D_garbage%20bags_60L_40pcs.jpg`

Comment: добавил её вопрос.  Тут она обрезается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что в данной ссылке используется русская буква `C`, которую тоже надо менять. 
Если это единичный случай, то воспользуйтесь:

```
$url = "http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/1020 СD_garbage bags_60L_40pcs.jpg";
$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
$url = str_replace("С", "%D0%A1", $url);

var_dump(getimagesize($url));die();
```

Если же массово, то для таких частей лучше использовать `urlencode`.

Comment: Благодарю за решение!